# Increase Query Speed Ionic/Laravel Post Request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to increase the speed of my query, currently it takes around **15 seconds** for all the data to get returned. I have an **Ionic 3** app which is sending a post request to get all inventory and my **Laravel 5.4** server is handling the request.

Here's my query :

```
    $input = file_get_contents( "php://input" );

    $request = json_decode( $input );
    $dealer_id = $request->dealer_id;

    $tmp = Inventory::where(
            'dealer_id', '=', $dealer_id
        )->where(
            'inventories.is_sold', '=', 0
        )->where(
            'is_active','=', 1
    );

    // dd($tmp);

    $data = collect();
    $pmt = $tmp->get();
    logger( sprintf('# of rows returned: %s', $pmt->count() ) );

    $pmt->each( function($row) use(&$data) {
      logger( sprintf('Row    : %s', $row->toJson() ));

        $data->push( array(
            'stock_number' => $row->stock_number,
            'vehicle_id' => $row->vehicle_id,
            'year' => $row->vehicle()->first()->year,
            'make' => $row->vehicle()->first()->make,
            'model' => $row->vehicle()->first()->model,
            // 'trim' => $row->vehicle()->first()->trim,
            'vin' => $row->vehicle()->first()->vin,
            'status' => $row->vehicle_status,
            'purchase_price' => $row->purchase_price,
            'cost' => $row->cost,
            // 'retail_price' => $row->retail_price,
            'search_meta' => $row->search_meta,
            // 'interior_color' => $row->vehicle()->first()->interior_color,
            // 'exterior_color' => $row->vehicle()->first()->exterior_color,
            'firstImg' => $row->getFirstImage(),
            'images' => Vimage::select('vehicle_id','name'
            )->where(
                'dealer_id', '=', $row->dealer_id
            )->where(
                'vehicle_id', '=', $row->vehicle_id
            )->get()
        ));

    });

    $statusKey = \App\lt_vehicle_status::where(
        'dealer_id', '=', $dealer_id
    )->where(
        'is_active','=', 1
    )->get();

    $response = [
       "status" => "Success",
       "code" => "MAC01",
       "reason" => "MAC - Inventory Gathered Successfully",
       "data" => $data,
       "status_keys" => $statusKey
   ];

   echo json_encode( $response );
```

Data Returned:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6gDO.png

One of the biggest issues is getting all the image urls as well as all the vehicles.

Thank you to whomever can help me try to increase my speed and efficiency of this.

Comment: Add a composite index on 'dealer_id', 'vehicle_id' and 'is_active' columns.

Comment: You are executing way too many queries in your loop. You have at least 6n queries as far as I see. For example: every time you use `$row->vehicle()->first()`, you are querying the database again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many queries to get the vehicles and images. In the vehicles case, you can reduce them to 1 for each `Inventory` record by eager-loading the relationship:

```
$tmp = Inventory::with('vehicle')
        where(
            'dealer_id', '=', $dealer_id
        )->where(
            'inventories.is_sold', '=', 0
        )->where(
            'is_active','=', 1
    );
```

If the image is a relationship on `Inventory` you can add it to the `with` method call, if not you can collect the image search parameters separately and then perform a single select

Comment: I'm trying out your route, currently it's searching through two tables and returning 163 raw results within 655 ms. I looped back through it and through it all back into my original json and the final speed is around is around 650 ms to return the data. The whole inventory now is gathered before the app even gets to the homepage now, which is awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you bring everything in a single query? Use `joins` and `select` only the needed columns. If you need an `array`, you just have to add `toArray()` and that's it. Also, add indexes if you don't have them.